# Log4j - log file per package

Tags: log4j

I am using log4j and I cant figure out, how to create log file for specific classes (in my case for security messages).

I want to have one global log, where I will log everything (INFO), and some package specific log files for debugging, testing and security of some parts of my app.

For instance I want to log only events from *LoggerListener* (Spring security) to file *security.log*, and only messages from my apps package *cz.flexibla2* *to flexibla2.log* etc.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j , that's probably pretty close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, Glenn's link is what you're looking for. Also google for "log4j additivity"

Comment: thanks, works for me....I had it configured in properties file, but it seems, that XML config is much more flexible.