# Log into an additional file at Apache Karaf

Tags: log4j, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have a system that uses both Apache Camel and Karaf.

I need some specific processor  to log into a new log instead of the default one ,karaf.log.

I have reached that there is a file called "org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg" that is responsible for logging configuration .

Here it's the file before I mess with it :

```
################################################################################
#
#    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
#    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
#    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
#    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
#    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
#    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#    limitations under the License.
#
################################################################################

# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, osgi:VmLogAppender
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer

# CONSOLE appender not used by default
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n

# File appender
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
log4j.appender.out.file=${karaf.data}/log/karaf.log
log4j.appender.out.append=true
log4j.appender.out.maxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.out.maxBackupIndex=10

# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name
log4j.appender.sift.default=karaf
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=${karaf.data}/log/$\\{bundle.name\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

Now I have added an extra File appender :

```
# Additional File appender
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, osgi:VmLogAppender  # I removed the first log4j.rootLogger    
log4j.appender.new=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.new.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.new.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
log4j.appender.new.file=${karaf.data}/log/new.log
log4j.appender.new.append=true
log4j.appender.new.maxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.new.maxBackupIndex=10
```

And from Camel , I logged from DSL :

```
process(exceptionProcessor).
      process(doSmth).log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"new","That is a new file to log into")
```

The result now that it logs erverything on BOTH "new.log" & "karaf.log" file .

The question is : how could I log into"new.log" just in case a specific processor .
Others will be logged into the karaf.log !!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j

Comment: Unfortunately it's not aswering my question as I use both Camel & Karaf

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is :

1- u should update "org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg" and add a new file appender .
In my case my new file appender is "new"

```
################################################################################
#
#    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
#    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
#    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
#    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
#    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
#    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#    limitations under the License.
#
################################################################################

# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out,osgi:VmLogAppender
log4j.logger.new=INFO,new
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer

# CONSOLE appender not used by default
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n



# new File appender
log4j.appender.new=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.new.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.new.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n 
log4j.appender.new.file=${karaf.data}/log/new.log 
log4j.appender.new.append=true 
log4j.appender.new.maxFileSize=1MB 
log4j.appender.new.maxBackupIndex=10 

# File appender
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
log4j.appender.out.file=${karaf.data}/log/karaf.log
log4j.appender.out.append=true
log4j.appender.out.maxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.out.maxBackupIndex=10



# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name
log4j.appender.sift.default=karaf
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=${karaf.data}/log/$\\{bundle.name\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

2- I use DSL to log :

```
process(doSmth).log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"new","HelloZ my new Logger ${exception.stacktrace}")
```

Enjoy :)