# how to define two loggers in log4j properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Basically,my requirement is that I have to log application related errors(let say log.error("") to a log file in my java application.

another log statements(let say log.warn("")) to SMTP mail server. Also the important thing is that, I have to to send email only once after the program execution completes. It should not be like for every log.warn().

I have very little knowledge on log4j.

can you please help me configure the log4j properties. I will be using SMTP server.

sample config file for this requirement exactly is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use a threshold for your appenders.

Please have a look at [How to configure log4j to log different log levels to different files for the same logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839647/how-to-configure-log4j-to-log-different-log-levels-to-different-files-for-the-sa) and [log different log levels to different files with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459943/log-different-log-levels-to-different-files-with-log4j)

Furthermore, for sending the email you can use SMTPAppender.

For some sample configs, please see : [Multiple log files with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474215/multiple-log-files-with-log4j)

And for a good tutorial, please see : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the links are showing for the same logger -> different log levels. But I want to two loggers each log to different file.

Comment: also my main requirement is that, mail should be sent at the end of all the log statements finished and not for every log.xXX().

Comment: If by "the end of all log statements" you mean the end of execution of some program or function or class file, you need to have a custom log implementation. 
By default the logging appenders are invoked on each call.
For custom behavior , you need a custom implementation.
HTH