# Log4j separate Log files

Tags: java, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating multiple log files of different content with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j)

I want to store Debug logs and info logs in separate files can anyone give me the sample.

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,R1,R2

log4j.appender.R2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R2.File=/Test/ex/ex.log
log4j.appender.R1.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy
log4j.appender.R2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

When I try the above, debug and info logs are storing in sample file. But how can I store separately.

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/q/728295/544983

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use a LevelMatchFilter provided by log4j.

Here an updated version of your configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,R1,R2

log4j.appender.R1.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy 
log4j.appender.R1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R1.File=/Test/error.log
log4j.appender.R1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m
log4j.appender.R1.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.R1.filter.1.LevelToMatch=ERROR
log4j.appender.R1.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.R1.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter

log4j.appender.R2.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy 
log4j.appender.R2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R2.File=/Test/info.log
log4j.appender.R2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m
log4j.appender.R2.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.R2.filter.1.LevelToMatch=INFO
log4j.appender.R2.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.R2.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter

log4j.appender.debug.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy 
log4j.appender.debug=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debug.File=/Test/debug.log
log4j.appender.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.debug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m
log4j.appender.debug.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.debug.filter.1.LevelToMatch=DEBUG
log4j.appender.debug.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.debug.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

References : 
  [PropertyConfiguration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29)
  [LevelMatchFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilter.html)