# How to specify 2 log4j files that both have separate class names in the log fiels

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j logging and am trying to log to different log files.
I also want to be able to show the class names in the different log files.
How do I instantiate my 2 different log files : serverFileLog and clientLogger.
I need to pass in the class name so the call to get logger I can't use the logger name.
Please HELP|!!!!!! Thank you!!

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, serverFileLog

## Server File Log

log4j.appender.serverFileLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.serverFileLog.File=./ServerLog.log
log4j.appender.serverFileLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.serverFileLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.additivity.serverFileLog=false

## Client File Log

log4j.appender.clientLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.clientLog.File=./Client.log
log4j.appender.clientLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.clientLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.clientLogger=DEBUG, clientLog
log4j.additivity.clientLogger = false

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiple log files of different content with log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j)

Comment: Yes I got my log files working except for this new problem of how to specify the class in the logs.

Comment: use %c only to print fully qualified class name

Comment: To instantiate log files I have to do a Logger.getLogger("clientLogger");  to get the client logger. This will use client logger as the class name in log file. I really need to do Logger.getLogger(Client.class) so that it uses the class name. But how do I get the correct logger client logger? I am going to have other classes within the client so I cant just use the logger name.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late to answer now, but I've just found the answer. Hope it can help you. 
You should use: `Logger.getLogger("clientLogger.ClassName")` instead of `Logger.getLogger("clientLogger")`