# How to logging an activity on my project

Tags: java, mysql, web, authentication, log4j

I've created a web java connect to Database (using MySQL ver5.6). On my web java there are the login panel username & password(the account username & password from DB). Now it's working ok but i want to logging activity ( login true or false) using Apache log4j.properties. Please help me complete it.!
Here is my code :

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public abstract class DBConnectionDAO {
public static Connection getConnection() {
    String stringConnection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_tai_khoan?user=root&password=password&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Open connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConnection);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Class not found! Please review your library");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Loi truy van");
    }
    return conn;
}
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBConnectionDAO.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DBConnectionDAO obj = new DBConnectionDAO() {};
    obj.runMe("hongson");

}

private void runMe(String parameter){

    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("This is debug : " + parameter);
    }

    if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
        logger.info("This is info : " + parameter);
    }

    logger.warn("This is warn : " + parameter);
    logger.error("This is error : " + parameter);
    logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + parameter);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Which version of log4j are you using?
Did you configure log4.xml or log4j.properties?

You can check this links in order to configure the log:

- [Creating multiple log files of different content with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j): this link has a good example using more than one file to log and to log just some classes.
- [Log4j Configuration Using Properties File](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/sample-log4j-properties-file-configuration-1.html)

You also might see the [Log4j documentation page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#Loggers) in order to understand the appenders.

Comment: Thanks bro, now i've done configuring my javaweb and database. But now i cant output logging file ( just output to console ) .Here is my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921579/logging-activity-using-apache-log4j

Comment: Have you got this kind of warning?

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger.
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

If yes, did not initiate log4j properly. You can dig on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly

Comment: No i dont receive any warning. It looks still ok without any warning. It just output to console but not output to a file
Should i edit the log4j-properties anymore?