# Configuring a class using a logger to log to a file with log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, configuration-files, fileappender

Hi I have 4 classes that each share anonymous instances of a logger class (not my creation). I have added a log4j appender and set the logger to log to the appender file. The problem is that everything is logging to the file including Hibernate. How do I set up the classes only to log to this file?

Here is my present configuration file:

```
# Direct log messages to a file
log4j.appender.file=com.daniels.logging.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=daniels.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S} %-5p [%c{1}:%M] - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.append=true

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
```

One of my classes is called SeriousEvent. If I would like this class to log to the file com.daniels.logging.RollingFileAppender how would I set this up? I'm new to logging so forgive me. I have looked through the documentation but I'm finding it hard getting a good example.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I think those links below can help you:

- [Creating multiple log files of different content with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j): this link has a good example using more than one file to log and to log just some classes.
- [Log4j Configuration Using Properties File](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/sample-log4j-properties-file-configuration-1.html)

You also might see the [Log4j documentation page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#Loggers) in order to understand the appenders.

One question: did you develop a customized appender for your system? I'm asking that because you added on your file:

```
log4j.appender.file=com.daniels.logging.RollingFileAppender
```

Seeing on log4j docs, this property should be and component appender, such as:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

Comment: Hi, I did create a custom appender. I have to mimic another application and it had done so although I might change that once everything is working.