# To create separate logs for particular set of messages in logback

Tags: logging, logback

I have a log file `main.log` where my every log message in the project will be logging into that file.

Now I want to create two more log files `pull.log` and `put.log` and move pull messages to pull.log and put message to put.log from the main.log file by using logback in java.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using log4j, this qustion hqve q response here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiple log files of different content with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j)